# Dependency resolving with App::make not working when bind is done by a provider in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2. I tried to resolve a dependency in Laravel out of the IOCContainer as follows.(with `App::make` method)

`App/FooController.php:-`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Bind\FooInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public  function outOfContainer(){
        dd(App::make('\App\bind\FooInterface')); // Focus: program dies here!!
    }
}
```

Bindings for the FooInterface done in the AppServiceProvider as follows

`App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:-`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Bind\Foo;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('\App\Bind\FooInterface', function() {
            return new Foo();
        });
    }
}
```

Structure of the Foo class as follows.

`App/Bind/Foo.php:-`

```
<?php

namespace App\Bind;


class Foo implements FooInterface {

}
```

Structure of the `FooInterface` interface as follows:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Bind;


interface FooInterface {

}
```

Then I created a route as follows.

```
Route::get('/outofcontainer', 'FooController@outOfContainer');
```

But when I navigate to this route it throws an exception with the error text:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 748:
Target [App\bind\FooInterface] is not instantiable.
```

What is going wrong with this?
How to use App:make() with the AppServiceProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service provider, you're binding the string `'\App\Bind\FooInterface'`. In your controller, you're attempting to make the string `'\App\bind\FooInterface'`. These strings are not the same, as they have differing cases (`Bind` vs `bind`). Since the strings are not the same, Laravel cannot find the binding in the container.

Correct the casing in your make statement and it should work:

```
dd(App::make('\App\Bind\FooInterface'));
```